# Efficient way to enumerate unique undirected paths

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, graph

Given a subset of nodes `{1,2,...,N}` is there any `STL` or `boost` function that returns unique *undirected* tours over all of them?

`std::next_permutation()` gives all `N!` *directed* tours, where `1-2-...-N` is different from `N-N-1-...-2-1`.

However, in this case, I don't want both of them, but only one of them. Essentially, I would like to enumerate only `N! / 2` of the tours.

The following code that uses `std::next_permutation()` and `unordered_set` works, but is there anything more efficient? The following code essentially generates all `N!` directed tours and discards half of them after checking against an `unordered_set()`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>

template <typename T, typename U> bool unorderedset_val_there_already_add_if_not(std::unordered_set<T, U>& uos, T& val) {
    if (uos.find(val) != uos.end())
        return true;//val already there
    uos.insert(val);
    return false;//Value is new.
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> sequence{ 1, 2, 3};
    std::unordered_set<std::vector<int>, boost::hash<std::vector<int>>> uos;

    do {
        printf("Considering ");
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < sequence.size(); i++)
            printf("%d ", sequence[i]);
        printf("\n");
        std::vector<int> rev_sequence = sequence;
        std::reverse(rev_sequence.begin(), rev_sequence.end());
        if (unorderedset_val_there_already_add_if_not(uos, sequence) || unorderedset_val_there_already_add_if_not(uos, rev_sequence)) {
            printf("Already there by itself or its reverse.\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("Sequence and its reverse are new.\n");
        }
    } while (std::next_permutation(sequence.begin(), sequence.end()));
    getchar();
}
```

That is, given `{1,2,3}`, I only want to enumerate `(1-2-3)`, `(1-3-2)` and `(2-1-3)`. The other three permutations `(2-3-1)`, `(3-1-2)` and `(3-2-1)` should not be enumerated because their reverse sequence have already been enumerated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stay with `next_permutation` rather than make own generator routine, the simplest way is filter out a half of permutation with some condition.

Very simple one: the last element should be larger than the first one.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include "stdio.h"

int main() {
    std::vector<int> sequence{ 1, 2, 3, 4};
    
    do {
        if (sequence[sequence.size()-1] > sequence[0]) {
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < sequence.size(); i++)
                printf("%d ", sequence[i]);
            printf("\n");
        }        
    } while (std::next_permutation(sequence.begin(), sequence.end()));
    getchar();
}

1 2 3 4 
1 2 4 3 
1 3 2 4 
1 3 4 2 
1 4 2 3 
1 4 3 2 
2 1 3 4 
2 1 4 3 
2 3 1 4 
2 4 1 3 
3 1 2 4 
3 2 1 4
```

Possible own implementation:

```
Generate all pairs (start; end)     where start < end  
  Generate all permutations of `n-2` values without start and end  
      For every permutation make {start, permutation.., end}

1 ... 2 + permutations of {3, 4}
1 3 4 2
1 4 3 2  
1 ... 3 + permutations of {2,4}
1 2 4 3
1 4 2 3  
...
3 ... 4 + permutations of {1, 2}
3 1 2 4
3 2 1 4  
...
```

Comment: Yes, I think this is more efficient than using unordered_set and hashes. Although, still N! would be enumerated. Do you have any generator in mind that goes through only N!/2 cases?

Comment: At this moment I don't see easy way of early stop in the fastest [next_perm](https://www.nayuki.io/page/next-lexicographical-permutation-algorithm) algorithm or in [Heap's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap's_algorithm) one because intermediate "bad" variants are needed to produce "good" ones later. Perhaps STL implementation is well-tuned and outperforms quick-made own implementations, so using filtering might be not a worst variant.

Comment: Just figured out :)  Will write in some minutes.

Comment: yes, I think your new edit would work without repetition. Thanks!